# Looping and find the minimum of a function and get data in excel sheet

Tags: mathematical-optimization, excel, infinite-loop

I have written a code. I want to change y from (*10^-4 to 10^-6) and want to find the corresponding minimum and then need to export the value of y and corresponding minimum in an excel sheet.  I know that probably this is very trivial.  But any help will be highly appreciated.

```
   y = 5*10^-8;
S = ( (3*10^14 - y/(4*10^-12) - x^2) + (I*x (7*10^7)))/(3*10^14 - y/(
     4*10^-12) - x^2 - (I*x*(9*10^7)));
U = ( Abs[S])^2;
minim = x /. Last[FindMinimum[U, {x, 5.8 10^7}]]
```

Comment: See `Table` and lookup `Export`/`xls`.

Comment: @Kuba: Thanks for your reply.  But I also need to increment my "y" and find the minimum corresponding to that "y". So how can be that done simultaneously?

Comment: Why not with `Table`?

Comment: @Kuba:Table[x /. Last[FindMinimum[U, {x, 5.8 10^7}]], {y, 5*10^-9, 5*10^-7, 
  1.98*10^-8}]. I tried something like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

We build a function `f` that has both `x` and `y` as arguments (don't assign a value to `y`). Next we define the function `minimum` in `y` that returns the corresponding minimal point `x`. Afterwards, we use `Table` to do the calculations for various `y = 10^z`. I use `10^z` in order to get a nicer stepping. Finally, we add some column titles with `Join` and export everything to the xls file `"a.xls"`. The file should appear in `Directory[]`. Of course, you can specify another file name and a whole path as first argument of `Export`.

```
ClearAll[y];
S = ((3 10^14 - y/(4 10^-12) - x^2) + (I x (7 10^7)))/(3 10^14 - y/(4 10^-12) - x^2 - (I x (9 10^7)));
U = (Abs[S])^2;
f = {x, y} \[Function] Evaluate[U // ComplexExpand // Simplify];
minimum = y \[Function] x /. Last[FindMinimum[f[x, y], {x, 58 10^6}]];
data = Table[{10^z, minimum[10^z]}, {z, -6, -4, 1/100}];
Export["a.xls", Join[{{"y", "minimum[y]"}}, data]]
```

Comment: I tried this in the real program (I just made up the numbers in the above program).  Once I run it, it's giving me an output error which tells me that  "encountered a gradient that is effectively zero. The result returned may not be maximum.  It may be a maximum or a saddle point".

Comment: Yes, I also observed that. You can use `minimum = 
 y \[Function] 
  Evaluate[x /. 
    Last[Simplify[Minimize[f[x, y], x], 10^-6 <= y <= 10^-4]]]` instead. This utilizes that this is one of the rare cases which as analytical solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I tried what you said.That doesn't seem to work.  My step size is actually very small (of the order of 10^-8).

Comment: So, what _exactly_ went wrong? It works on my machine, you know. Of course you have to adjust the step size in `Table`. You can also use `data = Table[{y, minimum[y]}, {z, 10^-6,10^ -4, 10^-8}];`.

Comment: My real code is as follows.a = 300*10^-6;
n = 1.44;
c = 3*10^8;
\[Lambda] = 1550*10^-9;
m = 0.96;p = (2/m - 1) + Sqrt[(2/m - 1)^2 - 1] ;
Q1 = 8*10^6;
Q2 = 1.98*10^8;
\[CapitalKappa]1 = (\[Pi]*c)/(\[Lambda]*Q1);
\[CapitalKappa]2 = (\[Pi]*c)/(\[Lambda]*Q2);
\[Tau] = (2*\[Pi]*a*n)/c;
T1 = (2*\[CapitalKappa]1*\[Tau])/(1 + 1/p);

Comment: :ClearAll[y];
S = ({((\[CapitalKappa]1*\[CapitalKappa]2 + y/\[Tau]^2) - x^2) - (
     T1*\[CapitalKappa]2)/\[Tau]} + 
   I*x (T1/\[Tau] - \[CapitalKappa]1 - \[CapitalKappa]2))/({((\
\[CapitalKappa]1*\[CapitalKappa]2 + y/\[Tau]^2) - x^2)} - 
   I (\[CapitalKappa]1 + \[CapitalKappa]2) x);
U = ( Abs[S])^2;
(*Plot[U,{\[CapitalOmega],1.45\[Times]10^7,5.8\[Times]10^7}]*)

Comment: f = {x, y} \[Function] Evaluate[U // ComplexExpand // Simplify];
minimum = 
  y \[Function] 
   Evaluate[
 @Henrik Schumacher:   x /. Last[Simplify[Minimize[f[x, y], x], 10^-9 <= y <= 10^-7]]];
data = Table[{10^z, minimum[10^z]}, {z, -9, -7, 2.45*10^-8}];
Export["a.xls", Join[{{"y", "minimum[y]"}}, data]]

Comment: It says the function value is not a number at x= -0.82953. It is also taking long time to execute